# Script to add armv6 architecture to iOS executable built with Xcode 4.5 Error

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, armv7, armv6

Could you help me a little?

If I use the following script:

```
# Find the common base directory for both build
XCODE_BUILD=${BUILD_ROOT%%/Build*}
# Change this to the full path where Xcode 4.4 (or below) puts your armv6 output, using the previously derived base
export ARMV6_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$XCODE_BUILD/Build/Products/Release_armv6-iphoneos/$EXECUTABLE_PATH"
```

then build is failed, and the message is the following:

```
Missing }.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my bug.

So if you change the above lines from the next lines, your application can build, and can archive too.

```
# Find the common base directory for both build
setenv XCODE_BUILD `echo $BUILD_ROOT| sed 's|Build.*||'`
echo $XCODE_BUILD
# Change this to the full path where Xcode 4.4 (or below) puts your armv6 output, using the previously derived base
setenv ARMV6_EXECUTABLE_PATH "$XCODE_BUILD/Build/Products/Release_armv6-iphoneos/$EXECUTABLE_PATH"
```